# How do i configure IIS7 for a website rather than a web application to be viewed through localhost?

Tags: iis-7

I want to view my "website" through localhost. I dont want to click on the play button in Visual Studios. I know with "web application", i would need to place the published files into a particular directory ( normally C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ ) and then view the application through Localhost.

However, i believe this would be different for "websites". How is this done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like a web application, you can put your website in a folder under c:\inetpub\wwwroot\, and browse to your site's URL. (For example, //localhost/mysite)

You could also open IIS Manager, right-click your website folder,  select "Manage Application", and then click "Browse". You website will open in your default browser.